# Chef Read File Pattern Matching

Tags: ruby, regex, chef-infra, chef-solo

I have a text/xml file that contains the following data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<GovernmentPolicy>
    <name>Sample Policy</name>
    <description>Policy set during enrollment</description>
    <Resources>
        <ResourceID>7619f915-420d-4220-993e-1d3f1bee0ba4</ResourceID>
    </Resources>
<GovernmentPolicy>
```

I wanted to read the following in my chef recipe so I have this. I wanted to get the value "7619f915-420d-4220-993e-1d3f1bee0ba4"
so I ran it thru my regexp. I am just not sure why I cannot match this.

```
ruby_block "Read GovernmentPolicy" do
  block do
    resourceID = ""
    governmentpolicies = "/temp/governmentpolicies.xml"
    if File.exists?("#{governmentpolicies}")
      f = File.open("#{governmentpolicies}", 'r')
      pattern = /^\<ResourceID\>/
      f.each {|line|    
        if pattern.match(line)
            puts("***************MATCH FOUND*******************")
            puts line

        end
      }
      f.close
      end
  end
end
```

Any hints?

Comment: With `=` you're assigning, try changing it to `==` to compare the left value with the right one.

Comment: And where does `match` come from?

Comment: I have edited the codeline...sorry I made a mistake, removing code clutter... But still cannot match it.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing XML using Regex is usually a bad idea. You might want to use a Ruby XML parser, like [Nokogiri](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri).

Comment: I have tried adding this in my Chef Ruby block "require 'nokogiri'" but it says cannot load file 'nokogiri'.  I used chef-solo 12, just dont know why and how to do it properly.

Comment: Add `chef_gem "nokogiri"` before. Not sure if chef ships with any other XML parser already.

Comment: We ship nokogiri in most of the Chef installer packages because it is hell to install. You really don't want to try and use `chef_gem`, it will either be slow or broken or both.

Comment: So a `require 'nokogiri'` should have worked, right?

Comment: Assuming an omnibus installer, yes, depending on the version of Chef and OS.

Comment: Unfortunately not.. I have this version Chef-Solo: 12.6.0. In a ruby block where I add require 'nokogiri', I am encountering the error cannot load file.